# Non-Null Enums like non-null Objects?

Tags: java, enums, null

I have some code that acquires a value for an enum:

```
StringUtils.isEmpty(getEnumMember().value());
```

The supporting code looks like this:

```
public CustomEnum getEnumMember() {
    return enumMember;
}

----

public enum CustomEnum {

    TEXT1("text1"),
    TEXT2("text2"),
    TEXT3("text3");

    private final String value;

    CustomEnum(String v) {
        value = v;
    }

    public String value() {
        return value;
   }

   ...
}
```

I am wondering if there is a way for getEnumMember to handle null enums in the same way I can handle null objects.  For example:

```
public CustomEnum getEnumMember() {
    if (enumMember ==null) {
        return new CustomEnum();
    }
    return enumMember;
}
```

But I cannot instantiate a "new CustomEnum".  How would you handle this so that getEnumMember() would not return a null?  I would prefer not to create a special enum value for "ENUM_IS_NULL("")".

Comment: You need a custom value for this. By the way, it's not always a good idea to do what you wrote in your example with normal objects either.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you create an enum, you're saying that any variable of that type will have one of a defined list of values - or be null.  That's inescapable.  So you must either accept the null, or determine an appropriate value - whether it is one of your existing enum values or a new one you add.  These are your only options.  The code `return new CustomEnum();` just doesn't make sense; you must be selecting one of the enumerated values, and you have to specify which one.

Answer (score 3):

Can't be done. Part of the idea of an enum is that all possible values are enumerated and you can't just add more.

You'll either have to do:

```
public enum CustomEnum {

    TEXT1("text1"),
    TEXT2("text2"),
    TEXT3("text3"),
    ENUM_IS_NULL("");
   ...
}
```

or:

```
StringUtils.isEmpty(getEnumMember() == null? "" : getEnumMember().value());
```

or handle `NullPointerException`s in `StringUtils.isEmpty`